# How to make multiline label in TextField react native?

Tags: react-native, textfield

this is my code

```
<View>
                <TextField
                  ref={this.layananMenu}
                  editable={false}
                  label={
                    'Produk investasi apa saja yang pernah kamu miliki?'
                  }
                  
                  value={this.state.product?.menuName}
                  renderRightAccessory={() =>
                    this.state.loadingUsaha ? ( //ganti
                      <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
                    ) : (
                      <Icon name={'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={24} />
                    )
                  }
                />
              </View>
```

and the result is :
[my code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7eV6.jpg)

my expectation is :
[my expectation from UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOn74.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOFlow.It can be done using multiline={true} or giving padding in the text field,`<TextField style={...}` Hope it would work.

```
<TextField 
      ref={this.layananMenu}
      editable={false}
      label={'Produk investasi apa saja yang pernah kamu miliki?'}
      multiline = {true}
    />
```

Comment: not work, the multiline works only in value

Comment: did you try it using padding/flex?

Answer (score 0):

Add multiline prop in TextField in this way:

```
<TextField 
 ref={this.layananMenu}
 editable={false}
 label={'Produk investasi apa saja yang pernah kamu miliki?'}
 multiline={true}
/>
```